# SQL: row_number: order by date asc Need Nulls to be Last

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, partition, row-number

Since my DBMS doesn't allow for 'Nulls Last' in an order by clause, I need help with the following.

row_number() over(Partition by a.ID order by a.Date asc

I need my rows to have a row number sequence by ID ordered by date ascending, but have the null date rows be LAST in my sequence. Obviously it'd be great if I could just say "NULLS LAST" in my order by, however, my dbms (MSSQL) doesn't allow for that.

FOR EXAMPLE what is currently happening:

```
ID   Date     ROW_NUMBER
1    NULL      1
1    1/2/17    2
1    1/3/17    3
2    NULL      1
2    2/2/17    2
2    2/3/17    3
2    2/4/17    4
```

what I WANT to happen:

```
ID   Date     ROW_NUMBER
1    1/2/17    1
1    1/3/17    2
1    NULL      3
2    2/2/17    1
2    2/3/17    2
2    2/4/17    3
2    NULL      4
```

Help? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add another key to the `order by`:

```
row_number() over (Partition by a.ID
                   order by (case when a.date is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                            a.Date asc
                  )
```

Comment: too bad you can't convert exclamation points into rep, Gordon, you might have passed Jon Skeet today.   ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On the fly, treat all null values as the maximum possible date, using ISNULL.

```
row_number() over(Partition by a.ID 
     order by ISNULL(a.Date, CAST('9999/12/31' AS DATETIME)) asc
)
```

Comment: Ah thank you :) This worked as well, but more messy though. Thank you!

Comment: If you think my answer is more messy, you should accept @Gordon Linoff's answer.  he was first with a working solution anyway. :-)